# Strange behavior of inline-block elements inside absolute positioned parent

Tags: html, css

I have few `<div>`s having `display:inline-block`, inside an `absolute` positioned parent `<div>`.

HTML

```
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='container'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'>&#64;</div>
    <div class='box'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
 margin:0;
}
html, body{
 height:100%;
}
#wrap{
 position:relative;
 background:lightgreen;
 height:100%;
}
#container{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 vertical-align:baseline;
}
.box{
 display:inline-block;
 width:80px;
 height:120px;
 background:white;
 border:1px solid;
}
```

When I add some ascii character codes in any of the `<div>`s, strangely other `<div>`s move up. if I remove the ascii character then all `<div>`s align perfectly in the same row.

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3Dy8n/2/)

I am aware of other ways for making this layout, I can make the boxes absolute and force them  to be positioned at the  bottom of the parent, I'm aware of css3 `flex`.

But I'm interested in this specific problem, can somebody **explain** why is this happening..? or how can I fix it as it is?

**Update**

I am not interested in fixing it, since there are many ways to achieve the same alignment. I just want to understand what's happening. The question is, the divs are being being aligned at the bottom by default. Why does the other divs suddenly aligns at the top when one of the divs have character inside it?
[Updated Fiddle with both scenarios](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3Dy8n/5/)

*side note: this only happens when I add text inside the elements, if I add an HTML element instead of a character all divs still aligns at the bottom.*

Comment: All that strange thing is the so-called **vertical alignment** which is applied only for **inline** elements (including inline-block), the empty `div` does not have any content for us to know where the **baseline** should be, but looks like it's positioned somehow by design at the very bottom of the `div` block, this baseline position will line through over the base lines of all the other elements in the current inline flow, hence you see the result. To fix this, simply set the `vertical-align` **explicitly** for all the `divs` or use the `:empty` selector to filter for only empty divs

Comment: Why does the empty divs doesn't have a baseline even if it's `height` is explicitly  set...? 
The real question is why does the other divs suddenly aligns at the top when one of the divs get a baseline?

Comment: the `height` has nothing to do with baseline, in fact the `line-height` is what should effect the baseline but it does effect only when the container contains something. When it's empty, looks like the default baseline is the bottom edge/border. Why is it so? I'm sure that **it's just a designed feature**. You just need to know its behavior and adjust your css accordingly to make it work...

Comment: If you were a designer, where will you position the baseline for an empty `div`? You may choose the top edge/border (instead of bottom edge/border), you may also choose the baseline determined by `line-height` which is the distance calculated from the top edge. So I think this question is suitable for some designer better than some programmer/developer. Although I think there may not any important reason to design it like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
.box{
 display:inline-block;
 width:80px;
 height:120px;
 background:white;
 border:1px solid;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

add vertical-align: top;
when